# Not able to FTPS to another server from EC2 under ALB and WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftps, alb

I'm having an issue whereby I'm not able to ftps to another server from my EC2.
If I run a simple command

```
lftp username:password@serverurl:2121
```

then proceed to ls, I will be stuck at `ls` at 0 [Connecting...]

The same command works fine from a local macbook or using Filezilla client to connect.
Previously it was working fine until WAF and ALB is added on top of this EC2.

Things I have tried:

1. I have tried setting passive mode to on for the ftp.
   2)Changing the security group of ALB and EC2 to accept all inbound and outbound traffic.
2. Internet gateway is attached to the route tables.
3. Pinging the DNS does resolve and show the server's IP.
4. Added their IP into WAF whitelisting

Thanks!

Comment: Why use ftp? It's ***ancient***. Use ssh/sftp.

Comment: we wish to tell that to our partner, but it is not under our control. 
all fault will always come back to us.